# How to Import excel file in background and get the report once file is uploaded?

Tags: signalr, azure-functions, asp.net-core-2.0, nservicebus, azureservicebus

I want to import an excel file in .net core 2.2 application but I want to make it a background process. Like user select file and I want to run the process in the background but once the file is imported I want the report and list of faulty users in some table. So what would be best approach. Is SignalR a good option? If yes, are there any helping links? For background process I can also use NServiceBus or Hangfire. But the biggest question is I want to free the thread. So how can I get the report back once the file is uploaded? Also can I use Azure function?

Comment: SignalR is only needed for realtime communications! If all you need to do is upload a file in the background you can look at some libraries that helps this can be achived easily https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/quick-start.html

Comment: Hangfire will only implement "fire & forgot" pattern. But I also need the response back once the file is uploaded

Comment: facing similar challenge, any suggessions, my stack is .net core, sql, c# , I am also open for new techs

Answer (score 0):

SignalR will only help you to notification your client of your event. So for example you can use Service-bus to send events to upload your files, and when your worker is done, the Service-bus can emit the completion message to your server, witch can be configured with SignalR to broadcast the message for your client.

The useful documentation about SignalR can be found here:

[Microsoft Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-2.2)

[An how to example](https://code-maze.com/netcore-signalr-angular/)

When speaking about background process, you should ask a different question not related to signalR. You can use workers to do your job that will be hosted else where. I recomend you to read this answer/question for your background task:

[Worker - having trouble to choose the best technology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57810132/worker-having-trouble-to-choose-the-best-technology)